# How can I safely expose a database view, read-only, giving users flexibility similar to an SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, web-services, rest, security

I know allowing users to write their own SQL queries sets off all sorts of injection-attack fears but I'd really like to give my users ultimate flexibility when it comes to querying a database view.

If the web service is only allowed read-only access to the view and no access to anything else and the query itself is scrubbed (single-quotes convert to two single-quotes) then is there anything wrong with this?

Is there some other practice that I could use to give them similar flexibility?

Comment: Why don't you use views?

Comment: I am using a view.  Sorry, I'll clarify in question.

Comment: One option is to index your data and put it in something like ElasticSearch.

Comment: You can create a data warehouses and data marts; that is the proper way to give users "that kind of flexibility."

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting something, sorry if that's the case. Is a SQL query sent to the web service as a string, and executed? How does changing quotes to two quotes help? How is that not vulnerable to injection? Or to put it another way, why do you need the webservice then? :)

Comment: We have regular CRUD operations already on this data already that we provide access to via RESTful web service.  Our older data access method is a CLI which passes SQL directly.  We'd like to move this to RESTful web services as well so I'm looking for an alternative other than passing SQL directly.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling ElasticSearch doesn't allow real-time querying of a database though, right?

Comment: @wsaxton: No, you need to feed it with data for indexing. You could just as well set up a read-only replica of your DB when I think about it.